# Check if the value from one table exists in another tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, trigger

I have one table (tbl1) with column ID, the values can be duplicated. I have others tables (tbl2, tbl3...) with column ID , values are unique.
I want to write a trigger on insert row in tbl1 and check if ID in new row has not exists in tbl2,tbl3.... There is part of my code.

```sql
    CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tbl1_ID
       ON dbo.tbl1
       AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN

       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       DECLARE @CHECK int

       SELECT OBJECTID,ID, ROW_NUMBER() over(Order by OBJECTID) as aID into #T1 
       from inserted where (ID is not null)

       SELECT @CHECK = COUNT(p.ID from #T1 as p where not exists (select e.ID 
                                                                  from dbo.tbl2 as e 
                                                                  where p.ID=e.ID))

       IF @CHECK>0
           BEGIN
                RAISERROR("ID ALREADY EXISTS",16,1);
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
           END
    END
```

I don't know how to check in a range of tables, they are stored in table JoinTables(f.ex.). I suppose I need function here.

Table JoinTables similar to

```
obID|firsttable|secondtable

 1  |   tbl1   |   tbl2 
 2  |   tbl1   |   tbl3
 3  |   tbl1   |   tbl4
 4  |   tblM   |   tbl5
 5  |   tblM   |   tbl6
```

Comment: A range of tables is in another table, for example JoinTables, and their names can be changed. and trigger should take actual table names.

Comment: I need check, if value 'ID' of the insered row exists  in related tables

Answer (score 2):

I think you could get it with a single statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_insert ON T1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 
                  1
              FROM
                  inserted
              JOIN
                  (
                   SELECT ID FROM T2
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT ID FROM T3
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT ID FROM T4
                  ) others
                  ON others.ID = inserted.ID)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'YES';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NO';
    END

END
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=85dd1b8609afaca726081816f3f660dc)*

Comment: @McNets the number of related tables can be changed, so I need dynamic query. I understand, what should I do, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your requirement is best suited for `Instead of Trigger`.

`Trigger` is best suited for your Requirement than `Function`.

Sample data of `joinTable`,

```
create table #oinTables(obID int,firsttable varchar(20),secondtable varchar(20))
insert into #oinTables values
 (1  ,  'tbl1'  ,  'tbl2')
, (2  ,   'tbl1'  ,   'tbl3')
 ,(3  ,   'tbl1' ,   'tbl4')
 ,(4 ,   'tblM' ,   'tbl5')
,( 5 ,   'tblM'  ,   'tbl6')
```

How many record  can each `firsttable` like tbl1 have ? `4-5 tables` ?

```
Dynamic query can be created in this manner,

    DECLARE @FirstTable VARCHAR(50)='tbl1'
    DECLARE @JoinCond varchar(500)=''

DECLARE @JoinValue varchar(500)=''

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000)=N''
declare @Exists int

--Inerted/Deleted Table cannot be use in dynamic Sql
--So put inserted column in #temp table

create table #Inserted(id int)
insert into #Inserted(id)
select id from tbl1 ;

;With CTE as
(
 select * ,
 CONCAT(' left join ',secondtable ,' t',obID,' on ',' t',obID,'.id',' = ','i.id') SqlCol
 ,CONCAT(' t',obID,'.id') ValueCol
 from #oinTables
 where firsttable=@FirstTable
  )

  select top 1
 @JoinCond= (select SqlCol+ ' ' from cte for  xml path(''))
 ,@JoinValue= (select ','+ValueCol from cte for  xml path(''))
  from CTE

  set @JoinValue= STUFF(@JoinValue,1,1,'') -- remove first comma without bug
  set @JoinValue=CONCAT('coalesce(',@JoinValue,')')

  set @Sql=concat(' SELECT @Exists='+@JoinValue+' FROM #Inserted i ' ,@JoinCond)

set @Sql=' '+ @Sql +' '              

print @Sql 
Exec sp_executesql @Sql 
                    ,N'@Exists int OUTPUT'
                    ,@Exists OUTPUT

select @Exists

 if(@Exists is not null )
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('ID ALREADY EXISTS',16,1);
        --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        print 'rollback'
    END

   drop table #oinTables,#Inserted
```

Then similarly create trigger for table `tblM`.

If you want to write same logic in `UDF` or `Procedure` then in place of `inserted` table you can use main table name like `tbl1, tblM` .

If `inserted` table contain less rows  like 5,10 or even 20 then it will perform ok.

You  can tell number of rows in each table and whether Id in each table is `Clustered Index` or not.

This `Script` can also be use to `Dynamically` get `TableName` and `Join` them.

Comment: @KurmarHarsh, idea is clear, thank you. Instead of trigger is really more suitable for me

Comment: @Lora, check my edited script with minor testing. It work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, is this what you meant?
This should generate a dynamic SQL command for you with all the tables in "JoinTables" (I used McNets's answer as basis):

```
/*
-- initialization:
IF OBJECT_ID('JoinTables') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE JoinTables;
CREATE TABLE JoinTables
(
    TableName SYSNAME
);
INSERT INTO JoinTables VALUES ('Table1'),('Table2'),('Table3')
*/
CREATE TRIGGER t1_insert ON T1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, ARITHABORT, XACT_ABORT ON;
    DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX), @Exists BIT
    SET @Exists = 0

    SELECT @CMD = ISNULL(@CMD + N'
        UNION ALL
        ', N'   ') + N'SELECT ID FROM ' + TableName
    FROM JoinTables

    SET @CMD = N'SELECT TOP 1 @Exists = 1
    FROM inserted INNER JOIN (
    ' + @CMD + N') AS others 
    ON others.ID = inserted.ID'

    --PRINT @CMD
    EXEC sp_executesql @CMD, N'@Exists BIT OUTPUT', @Exists = @Exists OUTPUT

    IF @Exists = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'YES';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NO';
    END
END
```

EDIT: As noted by others, the INSERTED and DELETED tables will not be accessible within the dynamic SQL context, so their contents would first need to be copied to temporary tables (e.g. #inserted and #deleted) in the main trigger code, and those should be the tables referenced by the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Is the INSERTED virtual table accessible in the context of the sp_executesql?  Have you tested that?

Comment: The virtual table is not accessible, but I modified as @HumarHash adviced, I put Inserted table in temp one